# 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' when trying to open file from LocalFolder

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-store-apps

The following line of code is throwing a System.UnauthorizedAccessException:

```
StorageFile file
    = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("ms-appx:///Assets/image.png");
```

Comment: As far as I know, windows-store apps can't do that. Maybe Im wrong though.

Comment: [Application Data Windows Storage Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder) check out this link and read how they are using the `Instances of the Object`

Comment: `Grant` he's definitely using it incorrectly the way that he has it set would have to be done like if he were to have `img src =` in his html, aspx, of java script web page

Answer (score 2):

```
var uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/image.png");
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
```